# How to get the subordinate list via javascript

Tags: javascript, html-lists

I have a problem. I get the receive information from my firestore database. This information I would like to be shown. The first function `getOrders(...)` shows the parent information, for example "All Prouct", "Date", "Amount". The function `getOrdersDetail(...)` shows the subordinate information. So every order has its order details.  I would like to show no these information in a list.

For example

```
<ul id="list">
        <li>Order 1</li>
        <ul>
            <li>Information 1</li>
            <li>Information 2</li>
        </ul>
        <li>Order 1</li>
        <ul>
            <li>Information 1</li>
        </ul>
    </ul>
```

My idea was to split the function `showOrders(...)` in `showOrders(...)` and `showOrdersDetails(...)`. But I don't know how to create subordinate li elements. ( May my Idea is not good and you have a better Idea ). I hope you can help me. I would be happy to read some answers! :) Thanks in advance.

**index.html**

```
<ul id="list">

</ul>
```

**script.js**

```
 function showOrdersDetail(produkt, datum, summe) {
      var text = produkt + " " + datum + " " + summe;
      listNode = document.getElementById('test'),
      liNode = document.createElement("li"),
      txtNode = document.createTextNode(text),

      liNode.appendChild(txtNode);
      listNode.appendChild(liNode);

    }

/**
 * Get all orders of the user
 * @param {user.uid} userid 
 */

    function getOrders(userid) {
      db.collection("users").doc(userid).collection("bestellungen").get().then(function(querySnapshot) {
        if(querySnapshot.empty) {
          console.log("empty");
        }  
        else {
          querySnapshot.forEach(function(doc) {
            showOrders(doc.data().produkte, doc.data().datum, doc.data().summe)
            //console.log(doc.id, " => ", doc.data());
            console.log(doc.id);
            //console.log(doc.data().datum);

            //console.log(doc.data().produkte);

            //console.log(doc.data().summe);
            getOrdersDetail(doc.id, userid);        
        });    
        }
    });
    }

    function getOrdersDetail(docid, userid) {
      db.collection("users").doc(userid).collection("bestellungen").doc(docid).collection("gesamtbestellungen").get().then(function(querySnapshot) {
        querySnapshot.forEach(function(doc) {
          console.log(doc.id, " => ", doc.data());
          //console.log(doc.data().produkt);
          //console.log(doc.data().preis);
          //console.log(doc.data().anzahl);
          //console.log(doc.data().summe);

        });    
      });
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

See the section `Nesting a list` within [ul: The Unordered List element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/ul)

Sub-lists should be INSIDE the individual list items (in your case for the orders).

```html
<ul>
  <li>first item</li>
  <li>second item     
  <!-- Look, the closing </li> tag is not placed here! -->
    <ul>
      <li>second item first subitem</li>
      <li>second item second subitem
      <!-- Same for the second nested unordered list! -->
        <ul>
          <li>second item second subitem first sub-subitem</li>
          <li>second item second subitem second sub-subitem</li>
          <li>second item second subitem third sub-subitem</li>
        </ul>
      </li> <!-- Closing </li> tag for the li that
                  contains the third unordered list -->
      <li>second item third subitem</li>
    </ul>
  <!-- Here is the closing </li> tag -->
  </li>
  <li>third item</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks you and how could I do that with JavaScript?